# SQL Server 2005 SP2 install Support files failed

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server-2005, msi, service-pack

I'm racking my brains trying to apply service pack 2 to a recently installed SQL Server 2005 installation on a Windows Server 2K3 64-bit

The error message from the installation is unhelpful:

> MSP Error: 1260  Windows cannot open this program because it has been
>   prevented by a software restriction. For more information, open the
>   event log

The event log says:

> Source: MsiInstaller Message body: The description for the event ID
>   (11260) in source (MsiIntstaller) cannot be found.

I've already reviewed microsoft kb=979302, whilst the suggested errors don't entirely apply so the hotfix won't work - I did try the registry change but the value of the ErrorMessageFile was correct.

Comment: try uninstalling kb2918614 if it is installed

Comment: What does kb2918614 do? I need to make sure as this is currently relatively live system so need to keep reboots down to a min.

Comment: it is an MSI security update that may cause issues when installing packages